# Is a Django QuerySet's `order_by` method additive?

Tags: django, django-queryset

Given the following model and query, what query will result if I call `order_by()` multiple times?

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    field_a = models.IntegerField()
    field_b = models.IntegerField()

qs = MyModel.objects.all().order_by('field_a')
qs = qs.order_by('field_b')
```

What SQL will `qs` generate?

```
ORDER BY field_a, field_b
```

or

```
ORDER BY field_b
```

?

That is, do subsequent calls to `order_by()` *override* previous calls, or add to them?

Comment: you can check it yourself by doing: `print qs.query`

Comment: I think you can use `qs.order_by('field_a, field_b')`

Comment: I guess I'm asking if subsequent `order_by` calls are additive. I've rephrased the title to represent that.

Comment: @karthikr I didn't know about the `query` property. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And the answer is, subsequent calls to `order_by` *override* prior calls:

```
In [7]: print MyModel.objects.all().order_by('field_a').order_by('field_b').query
SELECT "mymodel"."id", "mymodel"."field_a", "mymodel"."field_b" 
FROM "mymodel" 
ORDER BY "mymodel"."field_b" ASC
```